# cputime in MatLab

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics, computational-science

I am using cputime in MatLab to computer time of a program (see the attached figure). There is a problem, that is the results are not identical. More precisely, four calculations give four different results. What should I do to fix them.
Thank your for your support.[image]

Comment: Why would you expect the computation time to be the same each time you ran the code?

Comment: Check the documentation of `timeit` if you want more reliable estimates of short run times.  Otherwise, check out `tic` and `toc`.